# Coset leaders of perfect linear codes

Tags: group-theory, coding-theory, upper-lower-bounds

Given a $[5,3,3]_4$ perfect linear code, how is it possible to work out the number of cosets of this code with coset leader of given weight $i$?

I've tried messing about with the hamming bound and found that the number of distinct cosets is $\frac{4^5}{64} = 16$, but I can't seem to get any further.

There can only be one coset with coset leader of weight $0$, but how do I work out the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the number of distinct cosets of a linear code is given by $q^{n-k}$, thus there are $4^{5-3}=16$ cosets. The first coset of course will just be the code itself (trivial coset). To get the other cosets, pick an element of $F_4^5$ which is not yet listed as an element of any coset, and employ vector addition for that particular element to every element of the trivial coset. The resulting vectors will then form a new coset. You can easily check the coset leader since it should have the least (Hamming) weight amongst the vectors in a coset (NOTE: sometimes it might not be unique). Repeat the process until you get all 16 cosets (and coset leaders).

Comment: Note: I used $n$ to denote the length of the code and $k$ as the dimension of the code.

Comment: Is it true that every codevector in $F_4^5$ of weight less than or equal to $1$ is a unique coset leader? Hence there are $15$ cosets whose leader has weight $1$?

Comment: If the minimum distance of the code is $d$, then any vector of weight $\le(d-1)/2$ is the leader of its coset. This follows immediately from the triangle inequality (applied to the Hamming metric). If the weight of a vector $x$ is $w>(d-1)/2$, then $x$ may or may not be a coset leader. If $w>d/2$, then we can always find some vectors of weight $w$ that are not coset leaders. If $w=d/2$, then $x$ is a coset leader, but there may be other vectors of weight $w$ in the same coset.